# android buttons don't trigger event on every click

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I have a few TextViews that have onClickListener set to them. It is done in the most simple and basic way. It works, but it's not sensitive enough. Sometimes you have to click 2-3 times before the event (playing a sound) is triggered. I've read all the relevant  info I could find here (and generally via google) but none of the very few solutions worked for me. The TextViews are big (about half the screen's width wide and the same height).
I thought it might be a hardware limitation, but I have a few apps on my android with great clickable buttons. You can checkout the buttons on a free app called "Fractions". It's impossible to touch the buttons there without triggering their event, while my buttons often fail to trigger it.
I've tried to set OnTouchListener and that didn't help either.
Any suggestions?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MediaPlayer mpCorrect = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.correct);
    final MediaPlayer mpWrong = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wrong);

    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mpWrong.start();
        }
    });

    t.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mpCorrect.start();
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: I added the code. Basic and simple.

Comment: Consider moving your `MediaPlayer`s to their corresponding listener as a local field instead of a class field. Is it possible that loading the `MediaPlayer` is a blocking call? Could the `MediaPlayer` be in the process of loading, thus "ignoring" user input?

Comment: Yeah, it did the job. Thanks :)

Comment: Let me make that an answer, then! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `MediaPlayer` field declarations from the outer class, to it's corresponding listener.  Generally as a rule of thumb, I declare variables on first use. Except for special cases with exceptions and loops of course. Keeps a lot of weird undefined behavior away.